# Struggling to get a function called upon "onclick" in Google Scripts

Tags: html, google-apps-script, jscript

I am currently implementing a form in Google Scripts. Unfortunately, I am struggling getting a function called by clicking on a html-button. Here how it looks:

[Form UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNV0T.jpg)

After clicking on "Submit" I want to call a function to pass the parameters to the server to be processed. Therefor I implemented the function form_data() on the html-part. The code looks like this:

.gs-file (excerpt):

```
function showPrompt() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 

  var result = ui.prompt(
      'Please enter the Problem ID: ',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Process the user's response.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var rfsId = result.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    this.radiosOnADialog();
    //getData(rfsId);

  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {


  } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {

  }

}

function radiosOnADialog() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 

  console.log('Hello World');
  Logger.log('Hi');

  //Call the HTML file and set the width and height
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("testUI")
    .setWidth(200)
    .setHeight(150);

  //Display the dialog
  var dialog = ui.showModalDialog(html, "Select Output Language");

}

function runsies(values){
  //Display the values submitted from the dialog box in the Logger. 
  Logger.log(values);
};
```

.html-file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>

        <table>
          <col width="80">
          <col width="50">
          <tr>
            <th><strong>Language</strong></th>
            <th><strong></strong></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>English </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="english" value="en"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>German </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="german" value="de"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <button  onclick="form_data()"> Submit </button>
        <button  onclick="google.script.host.close()"> Close </button>


    </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
      function form_data(){
       Logger.log("Values are:");
        var values = [{
          "english":$("input[name=english]:checked").val(),
          "german":$("input[name=german]:checked").val(),
        }];
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeIt()).runsies(values);
      };

      function closeIt(){
        google.script.host.close()
      };

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a problem? See [mcve]. Specifically, **Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question.**

Answer (score 1):

You're missing quotes in the `form_data` function.

Before:

```
function form_data(){
       Logger.log("Values are:");
        var values = [{
          "english":$("input[name=english]:checked").val(),
          "german":$("input[name=german]:checked").val(),
        }];
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeIt()).runsies(values);
      };
```

After:

```
function form_data(){
       Logger.log("Values are:");
        var values = [{
          "english":$("input[name='english']:checked").val(),
          "german":$("input[name='german']:checked").val(),
        }];
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeIt()).runsies(values);
      };
```

Notice the added single-quotes here:

```
"english":$("input[name='english']:checked").val(),
```

And here:

```
"german":$("input[name='german']:checked").val(),
```

Comment: Hey Rob! Thanks for the hint! Changed it. Unfortunately does not change the behavior of the function. Sill no response nor logging.